# Websocket/TCP connection to an EC2 instance from AWS Lambda?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-lambda, websocket

Is it possible to initiate a temporary (10 mins) Websocket/TCP connection to a server on an EC2 instance from AWS Lambda?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's possible under a few conditions:

- your Lambda Timeout is greater than 10 minutes
- your Lambda Function is deployed into a VPC (only if the EC2 instance isn't accessible from the Internet)
- The security groups on the instance and the Lambda function allow connectivity
- The connection is initiated from your Lambda function (as Lambda execution contexts can't accept inbound connections)

Comment: I don't see the need for a VPC other than best practice.

Comment: Ups, good point @stdundbar. I wrote that based on the assumption that the EC2 instance is in a private subnet - will update :)